# Exibir caixa de dialogo ao clicar com o botão direito

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho um formulário com multiplos campos e quero por a opção do usuario inserir um comentario no valor do campo.

Exemplo:

```
<form>
  <input type='text' id='campo'>
  <input type='hidden' id='comentario'>
  <submit>
</form>
```

O que quero fazer é que ao clicar com o botão direito no `input[id=campo]`ele mostre um balão para eu colocar um texto e esse texto vai ficar no `value` do meu campo `input[id=comentario]`.

Alguem pode me dar um exmplo de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz pequenas modificações no JsFiddle da resposta comentada.

[Teste aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/0d3ketxk/14/)

HTML:

```
<div class="content">    
    <input type="text" placeholder="Clique aqui com o botão direito para comentar" />   
    <div id="comentario" style="display:none">
        <form>
            <textarea></textarea>
            <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>    
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
 $("div.content").oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

  $('input[type=text]').mousedown(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      $('#comentario').show();
    } 
    return false;
  });
```

Comment: É quase isso, só preciso juntar com um outro projeto que tenho, porque quero fazer essa caixa aparecer dentro de um balão e na hora que clicar fora o balão sumir e ficar um marcador na caixa. E ai o submit é nos dois input.

Comment: Quando clico com o botão direito ele ainda abre a caixa de dialogo padrão, tem como fazer ela sumir?

Comment: segue um código com teste com tudo: http://codepen.io/MarciusMcflay/pen/YWKEJe